# Align two dataframe columns and preserve the order (no lexicographical reorder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm

Let A and B two dataframes columns:

| Hello | Foo | Hey | Bar | World |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Hello | Bar | Doo | World | Star |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to obtain the columns of a dataframe C containing all the unique columns in their concatenation BUT the columns must be in the same order as before.

| Hello | Foo | Bar | Hey | Doo | World | Star |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

In other words: "If A is an older version of a dataframe and B is a newer, how to get a dataframe C which keeps track of A deleted columns (not present in B) and B added columns (not present in A) in a way that keeps the ordering consistent with A (or B)?".

The method align can mix the two dataframe columns but it does not preserve the original order, the order is in lexicographical order.

Comment: Shouldn't "Hey" come before "Bar" since it's before it in A?

Comment: By deleting and inserting you can get situations where it is impossible to find a solution which keeps the order of both dataframes columns. Unless you guarantee never to insert a column with the same name as one which was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really want to keep the original order in both Indexes (and assuming there is no circular pattern), you can use the following algorithm:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Hello', 'Foo', 'Hey', 'Bar', 'World'])
B = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Hello', 'Bar', 'Doo', 'World', 'Star'])

def merge(A, B):
    sA = set(A)
    sB = set(B)
    out = {}
    while sA or sB:  # while items are left in A or B
        for a in A:          # take from A while not in B
            sA.discard(a)
            if a in sB:
                break
            out.setdefault(a)
        for b in B:          # take from B while not in A
            sB.discard(b)
            if b in sA:
                break
            out.setdefault(b)
    return list(out)

out = merge(A, B)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'Foo', 'Hey', 'Bar', 'Doo', 'World', 'Star']
```

##### generic solution

Alternatively, you can use graph theory, construct a directed graph with all the pairs of successive columns as edges using [`networkx.from_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_edgelist.html) and [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise), then find the longest path with [`dag_longest_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path.html):

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import pairwise

dfs = [A, B]
G = nx.from_edgelist((pair for pairs in map(pairwise, dfs) for pair in pairs),
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph)
C_cols = nx.dag_longest_path(G)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'Foo', 'Hey', 'Bar', 'Doo', 'World', 'Star']
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Perfectly what I was searching for! Thank you very much for this great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'd reduce this to a list parsing problem. Start by getting column lists:

```
a_cols = A.columns
b_cols = B.columns
```

Then apply your matching logic:

```
c_cols = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c_cols.append(a_cols[i])
    c_cols.append(b_cols[i])
```

Then you can reorder your `C` dataframe by merely doing `C.columns = c_cols`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = A.columns.tolist()
b = B.columns.tolist()
i = 0
j = 0
x = []
while i <len(a) or j<len(b):
  if i<len(a):
    if a[i] not in x: x.append(a[i])
    i+=1
  if j<len(b):
    if b[j] not in x: x.append(b[j])
    j+=1
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=x)
```