# How to make connections between two wells?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of wells that stores two `wells` and the contents of these wells in the form  `[depth interval from, depth interval to, soil description]`

```
wells = [
    [[0, -4, 'soil'], [-4, -8, 'clay'], [-8, -12, ' gravel'], [-12, -20, 'sand'], [-20, -24, 'basalts']],
    [[0, -4, 'soil'], [-4, -16, 'sand'], [-16, -20, 'galka'], [-20, -32, 'pebble'], [-32, -36, 'basalts']]
]
```

We need to draw lines between all the soil layers so that we can get a full geological section with all the layers

This is what these two wells look like, where different or identical rocks are marked in color. you need to connect all the same rocks and correctly identify those rocks that are only in one well

[image: WELLS]

and this is what the final result of all connections looks like:

[image: LINES_ON_WELLS]

all these connections can be made based on the data that I provided.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wells = [
    [[0, -4, 'soil'], [-4, -8, 'clay'], [-8, -12, ' gravel'], [-12, -20, 'sand'], [-20, -24, 'basalts']],
    [[0, -4, 'soil'], [-4, -16, 'sand'], [-16, -20, 'galka'], [-20, -32, 'pebble'], [-32, -36, 'basalts']]
]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

depths_dict = {}
colors = {'soil': 'red', 'sand': 'blue', 'gravel': 'green', 'pebble': 'orange', 'basalts': 'purple', 'clay': 'brown', 'galka': 'pink'}

for well_index, well in enumerate(wells):
    for interval in well:
        start_depth, end_depth, description = interval
        color = colors.get(description, 'gray')
        if description in depths_dict:
            ax.plot([well_index - 1, well_index], [depths_dict[description][0], start_depth], color=color, linestyle='--')
            ax.plot([well_index - 1, well_index], [depths_dict[description][1], end_depth], color=color, linestyle='--')
        depths_dict[description] = (start_depth, end_depth)
        ax.plot([well_index, well_index], [start_depth, end_depth], color=color, label=description)

ax.set_xlabel('Wells')
ax.set_ylabel('Depth')
ax.set_title('Profile')

legend_handles = [plt.Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor=colors[rock], markersize=10, label=rock) for rock in colors]
ax.legend(handles=legend_handles)

plt.show()
```

but this code connects intervals with the same description

Comment: Could you be more specific about what it is you are asking?

Comment: Can you have duplicated descriptions in the wells (e.g. two times "sand"), and if yes how should it be handled?

Comment: @thom747, Simply put, I want to understand how to create soil separation lines between wells. this is called the lithology of the geological section

Comment: @mozway, So far there have been no such situations, but in theory this could happen, but let's ignore that for now

Comment: @EdwardZotov then you could have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77112334) in which I showed how to align two iterables in order. If you adapt the code (something like `G = nx.from_edgelist((pair for pairs in (pairwise([x[-1] for x in l]) for l in wells) for pair in pairs), create_using=nx.DiGraph) ; order = nx.dag_longest_path(G)`) this should give you the absolute order of the sections ([as a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUd3K.png)).

Comment: @mozway, I didn't quite understand your answer. I need my code to specifically show which points need to be connected to each other to get the desired result

Comment: @EdwardZotov sorry I was a bit too quick. If you can get the absolute order of the layers, then you can determine which was/were the previous non-matching ones for any level

Comment: @mozway, The result of the code should look like this:

"-4 connects to -4"
"-8 connects to -4"
"-12 connects to -4"
"-20 connects to -16"
"-20 connects to -20"
"-20 connects to -32"
"-24 connects to -36"

Comment: @mozway, please, if it’s not difficult for you and you understand the essence, implement this solution in code

Comment: @mozway, Now I can say for sure - yes. therefore, apparently the code should analyze all layers step by step, and not all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i had to do was compare all the layers from top to bottom and draw connections so that the deeper layers lay lower than the shallower ones

```
wells = [
    [
        [24, 20, 'basalts'],
        [20, 12, 'sand'],
        [12, 8, 'graviy'],
        [8, 4, 'clay'],
        [4, 0, 'soil']
    ],
    [
        [36, 32, 'basalts'],
        [32, 20, 'galka'],
        [20, 16, 'sheben'],
        [16, 4, 'sand'],
        [4, 0, 'soil']
    ]
]

def lith_layers_comparison(well_1, well_2):
    matching_points = []

    i, j = 0, 0

    while i < len(well_1) and j < len(well_2):
        p1, p2 = well_1[i], well_2[j]

        if p1[2] == p2[2]:
            matching_points.extend([[p1[0], p2[0]], [p1[1], p2[1]]])
            i, j = i + 1, j + 1
        elif p1[2] != p2[2] and p1[1] < p2[1]:
            matching_points.append([p1[0], p2[1]])
            j += 1
        elif p1[2] != p2[2] and p1[1] > p2[1]:
            matching_points.append([p1[1], p2[0]])
            i += 1
        elif p1[2] != p2[2] and p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[0] < p2[0]:
            matching_points.append([p1[0], p2[1]])
            j += 1
        elif p1[2] != p2[2] and p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[0] > p2[0]:
            matching_points.append([p1[1], p2[0]])
            i += 1
        elif p1[2] != p2[2] and p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[0] == p2[0]:
            if p1[3] > p2[3]:
                matching_points.append([p1[0], p2[1]])
                j += 1
            else:
                matching_points.append([p1[1], p2[0]])
                i += 1

    return matching_points

reversed_connections = []
for i in range(len(wells) - 1):
    connections = lith_layers_comparison(wells[i], wells[i+1])
    filtered_connections = []
    for connection in connections:
        if connection not in filtered_connections:
            filtered_connections.append(connection)
    reversed_connections.append(filtered_connections)

sorted_connections = [[list(map(lambda x: -x, sub)) for sub in sublist[::-1]] for sublist in reversed_connections]

print(sorted_connections)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mozway suggested, you can generate an ordered iterable of all descriptions by aligning the available descriptions of all wells. With his slightly modified [merge() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111833/align-two-dataframe-columns-and-preserve-the-order-no-lexicographical-reorder/77112334#77112334) you could do something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this function is based on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111833/align-two-dataframe-columns-and-preserve-the-order-no-lexicographical-reorder/77112334#77112334
def merge(A, B):
    """Merges two tuples preserving the order of their elements.
    If the tuples have identical but differently ordered elements, one way to order them is chosen for the result."""
    sA = set(A)
    sB = set(B)
    out = {}
    i = 0
    j = 0
    i_n = 0
    j_n = 0
    while sA or sB:  # while items are left in A or B
        for a in A[i_n:]:          # take from A while not in B
            sA.discard(a)
            i = i + 1  # next A index
            if a in sB:
                i_n = i  # save the next A index to start from when looping through A the next time
                break
            out.setdefault(a)
        for b in B[j_n:]:          # take from B while not in A
            j = j + 1  # next B index
            sB.discard(b)
            if b in sA:
                j_n = j # save the next B index to start from when looping through B the next time
                break
            out.setdefault(b)
    return list(out)

wells = [
    [[0, -4, 'soil'], [-4, -8, 'clay'], [-8, -12, 'gravel'], [-12, -20, 'sand'], [-20, -24, 'basalts']],
    [[0, -4, 'soil'], [-4, -16, 'sand'], [-16, -20, 'galka'], [-20, -32, 'pebble'], [-32, -36, 'basalts']]
]

# generate unique ordered descriptions
descriptions = []
for well in wells:
    descriptions = merge([interval[2] for interval in well], descriptions)

# generate corrected wells data, with zero-depth intervals
corrected_wells = []
for well in wells:
    prev_end_depth = 0
    corrected_intervals = []
    i = 0
    for d in descriptions:
        for interval in well[i:]:
            # current interval
            start_depth, end_depth, description = interval
            if description != d:
                # insert a zero-depth interval
                if i > 0:
                    prev_end_depth = well[i - 1][1]
                corrected_intervals.append([prev_end_depth, prev_end_depth, d])
                # go to check the next description against the one from the current interval
                break
            else:
                # just copy the current interval
                corrected_intervals.append(interval)
                # go to check the next description against the one from the next interval
                i = i + 1
                break
    
    # check if any descriptions are still absent in the corrected intervals
    if len(corrected_intervals) < len(descriptions):
        prev_end_depth = well[i - 1][1]  # previous depth is the same for all trailing zero-depth layers
        for d in descriptions[len(corrected_intervals):]:
            corrected_intervals.append([prev_end_depth, prev_end_depth, d])
    
    corrected_wells.append(corrected_intervals)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

depths_dict = {}
colors = {'soil': 'red', 'sand': 'blue', 'gravel': 'green', 'pebble': 'orange', 'basalts': 'purple', 'clay': 'brown', 'galka': 'pink'}

for well_index, well in enumerate(corrected_wells):
    for interval_index, interval in enumerate(well):
        start_depth, end_depth, description = interval
        color = colors.get(description, 'gray')
        if description in depths_dict:
            # draw lines only for non-zero-depth layers
            if (depths_dict[description][0] != depths_dict[description][1]) or (start_depth != end_depth):
                ax.plot([well_index - 1, well_index], [depths_dict[description][0], start_depth], color=color, linestyle='--')
                # draw the bottom line only for the deepest layer
                if interval_index == len(well) - 1:
                    ax.plot([well_index - 1, well_index], [depths_dict[description][1], end_depth], color=color, linestyle='--')
        depths_dict[description] = (start_depth, end_depth)
        ax.plot([well_index, well_index], [start_depth, end_depth], color=color, label=description)

ax.set_xlabel('Wells')
ax.set_ylabel('Depth [m]')
ax.set_title('Profile')

ax.set_xticks(range(len(wells)))
wells_names = ['Well {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(len(wells))]
ax.set_xticklabels(wells_names)

legend_handles = [plt.Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor=colors[rock], markersize=10, label=rock) for rock in descriptions]
ax.legend(handles=legend_handles)

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

But, in my opinion, it is much better to have a tuple of all possible descriptions in the right order. Then you could define and visualize depth of your wells with [matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot) like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

layers = ('soil', 'clay', 'gravel', 'sand', 'galka', 'pebble', 'basalts')
colors_dict = {'soil': 'red', 'sand': 'blue', 'gravel': 'green', 'pebble': 'orange', 'basalts': 'purple', 'clay': 'brown', 'galka': 'pink'}

depths = [
[-4, -4],
[-4, 0],
[-4, 0],
[-8, -12],
[0, -4],
[0, -12],
[-4, -4]
]

total_depths = [0] * len(depths[0])
for layer_depth in depths:
    for i, well_layer_depth in enumerate(layer_depth):
        total_depths[i] = total_depths[i] + well_layer_depth

wells_names = ['Well {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(len(total_depths))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = [colors_dict[l] for l in layers]
x = range(len(total_depths))
ax.stackplot(x, depths, labels=layers, colors=colors)
min_y, max_y = ax.get_ylim()
ax.vlines(x, [min_y] * len(total_depths), total_depths, linestyle='--', color='black')
ax.set_xlabel('Wells')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(wells_names)
ax.set_ylabel('Depth [m]')
ax.set_title('Profile')

fig.legend(loc='center right')

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Why does the code sometimes run when I enter different data and nothing happens forever?

Comment: The code doesn't make sure the data is correct, so I don't know what would happen if the depth values were muddled up or duplicated layers were present, for example. By different data you mean different contents of the "wells" list, right? If it's not too big, post it in a comment, please. If it's really big, provide some description of what's there, like the number of wells, the number of layers, etc.

Comment: ok, no difference. this is the data with which the endless wait begins: wells = [
    [
        [0, -0.4, 'soil'],
        [-0.4, -0.8, 'clay'],
        [-0.8, -3.2, 'gravel'],
        [-3.2, -3.6, 'pebble'],
        [-3.6, -4.4, 'basalt']
    ],
    [
        [0, -0.4, 'soil'],
        [-0.4, -2.8, 'sand'],
        [-2.8, -4, 'boulder'],
        [-4, -5.2, 'basalt']
    ],
    [
        [0, -0.4, 'soil'],
        [-0.4, -1.6, 'clay'],
        [-1.6, -3.2, 'cobblestone'],
        [-3.2, -4.4, 'boulder'],
        [-4.4, -5.6, 'basalt']
    ]
]
 i use the first code

Comment: I see the same kind of thing. When I hit "Ctrl+C" to interrupt the program, Python shows a KeyboardInterrupt in merge() - so it looks like it fails to combine these descriptions. When I print "descriptions" right after the call to merge(), I see that it changes like this: first it becomes ['soil', 'clay', 'gravel', 'pebble', 'basalts'], then it becomes ['soil', 'sand', 'boulder', 'clay', 'gravel', 'pebble', 'basalts'] when 'sand' and 'boulder' are added, and then merge() is in endless loop - it should insert 'cobblestone' between 'clay' and 'boulder', but their order is already reversed...

Comment: I guess, the best way to deal with it is to use a strictly defined order of layers (like in the second part of my answer). Alternatively, ask @mozway about what can be done with that merge() function to ensure it works also in such a case.

Comment: I have already updated the code in the first part of my answer above. Try it with your bigger data set.

Comment: This worked with the dataset I provided. but it don't work with a large set. I do not understand what the problem is. the Problem is not the input data or its volume, because I rearrange the entered words differently between each other and it starts to work

I can send you the full data set if you don't mind helping me. Tell me where can I send them?

Comment: and the second code is not entirely clear to me, because the depth data entered here looks unclear to me. I only need to enter data the way I showed in my question

Comment: By the way, if I divide my input data into halves, then both of them are executed correctly separately. but if you combine them back, the code will not run. However, I added the same first half to the first half of the data, and everything worked. That is, it is not a matter of volume.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256611/discussion-between-ratislaus-and-edward-zotov).